# What mobile variables are available for device signature analysis?

Tags: security, authentication, mobile, detection

I'm building a list of variables available on mobile devices, for device signature analysis. Here is what I've identified so far. Please help me fill out the list. Thanks!

**General HTTP Variables**

- IP Address
- Cookie
- User Agent

**Smart Phone Variables**

- Device ID
- Geolocation
- Device MAC Address

**Javascript Variables**

- Current Time
- Time Zone
- Screen Size
- Supported Fonts
- Preferred Language
- Installed Components
- Cookies Enabled

---

The general pattern for getting variables might look something like this:
[image]

Comment: You may be referring to this as Device ID however IMEI is generally the unique number used to identify phones. IMSI can be used to identify the subscriber (SIM card). For tables and devices without a SIM card your best bet for unique identity is MAC address although this can be tampered with. Note, you can't get all these programmatically on all platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Panopticlick project](http://panopticlick.eff.org/) fingerprints browsers using a verity of techniques.  This includes version numbers of the browser and all isntalled components (Flash, java, ect).  The Project also looks at supported fonts,  and prefered language, screen size and time zone.

[Check out the results](http://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes).

Comment: It's interesting that TimeZone is identified. Do you know how that works? I assume the service is doing a IP address translation to a geolocation, then using the time zone for that geo point. But I could be way off - thoughts?

Comment: @paul actually I think thats obtained using JavaScript's `Date.getTime()` method.  A lot of Panopticlick's magic is from creative JavaScript.

Comment: Ahhh, I forgot about JavaScript. Thanks, I'll add that to the list. I think this is the function: `Date.getTimezoneOffset()`